# Extracting feature names from sklearn column transformer

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, pipeline

I'm using `sklearn.pipeline` to transform my features and fit a model, so my general flow looks like this: column transformer --> general pipeline --> model. I would like to be able to extract feature names from the column transformer (since the following step, general pipeline applies the same transformation to all columns, e.g. nan_to_zero) and use them for model explainability (e.g. feature importance). I'd also like it to work with custom transformer classes too.

Here is the set up:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import compose, pipeline, preprocessing

df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2, 3], "b": [1, 2, 3], "c": ["x", "y", "z"]})
column_transformer = compose.make_column_transformer(
   (preprocessing.StandardScaler(), ["a", "b"]),
   (preprocessing.KBinsDiscretizer(n_bins=2, encode="ordinal"), ["a"]),
   (preprocessing.OneHotEncoder(), ["c"]),
)
pipe = pipeline.Pipeline([
   ("transform", column_transformer),
   ("nan_to_num", preprocessing.FunctionTransformer(np.nan_to_num, validate=False))
])
pipe.fit_transform(df)  # returns a numpy array
```

So far I've tried using [get_feature_names_out](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html#sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.get_feature_names_out), e.g.:

```
pipe.named_steps["transform"].get_feature_names_out()
```

But I'm running into `get_feature_names_out() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`, not sure what's going on but this entire process doesn't feel right. Is there a better way to do it?

**EDIT:** A big thank you to @amiola for answering the question, that was indeed the problem. I just wanted to add another important point for posterity: I was having other problems with my own custom pipeline and I was getting an error `get_feature_names_out() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`. So it turns out, aside from the `KBinsDiscretizer` there was another bug in my custom transformer classes. I implemented the `get_feature_names_out` method, but it was not accepting any parameter on my end and that was the problem. If you run into similar issues, then make sure that this method has the following signature: `get_feature_names_out(self, input_features) -> List[str]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the problem is generated by the `encode="ordinal"` parameter passed to the `KBinsDiscretizer` constructor. The bug is tracked in [GitHub issue #22731](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/22731) and [GitHub issue #22841](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/22841) and solved with [PR #22735](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/22735).

Indeed, you might see that by specifying `encode="onehot"` you might get a consistent result:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import compose, pipeline, preprocessing

df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2, 3], "b": [1, 2, 3], "c": ["x", "y", "z"]})
column_transformer = compose.make_column_transformer(
   (preprocessing.StandardScaler(), ["a", "b"]),
   (preprocessing.KBinsDiscretizer(n_bins=2, encode="onehot"), ["a"]),
   (preprocessing.OneHotEncoder(), ["c"]),
)
pipe = pipeline.Pipeline([
   ("transform", column_transformer),
   ("nan_to_num", preprocessing.FunctionTransformer(np.nan_to_num, validate=False))
])
pipe.fit_transform(df) 

pipe.named_steps['transform'].get_feature_names_out()

# array(['standardscaler__a', 'standardscaler__b', 'kbinsdiscretizer__a_0.0', 'kbinsdiscretizer__a_1.0','onehotencoder__c_x', 'onehotencoder__c_y', 'onehotencoder__c_z'], dtype=object)
```

Besides this, everything seems fine to me.

Eventually, apparently, even installing the [nightly builds](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/advanced_installation.html#installing-nightly-builds), I still get the same error.

Comment: Thank you! That was indeed the problem. I discovered another problem in my code and I updated my original post with my own solution to the other problem